# custom Permalinks with Post Meta Value , other pages return only homepage error

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have a directory site, so I created a post type name "`ads`" and their post title are phone numbers, but I want the permalinks instead of `mysite.com/ads/post_title` I want it `mysite.com/post_meta_city/post_title` and here's my code:

```
function ads_add_rewrite_rules(){

global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%post_ads_city%', '([^/]+)', 'post_ads_city=');

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%ads%', '([^/]+)', 'ads=');


$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('ads', '%post_ads_city%/%ads%', false);

}add_action('init', 'ads_add_rewrite_rules');


function ads_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename)
{
if ($post->post_type != 'ads' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))){
    return $permalink;
}else{
    $no_data = 'no-city';

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $var1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_ads_city', true);

    $var1 = sanitize_title($var1);

    if(!$var1) {
        $var1 = $no_data;
    }

    //$permalink = str_replace('?ads=', $var1."/", $permalink);
    $permalink = str_replace('%post_ads_city%', $var1, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}

}add_filter('post_type_link', 'ads_permalink', 10, 3);
```

Yes i achieve the url that I want, but the problem is when i visit the other pages on my site, it returns only the homepage, is there away to fix this? without adding a something hard coded on the add permastruct? please help.

By the way the site i am doing has an existing site so its important for me to keep the urls.

Answer (score 1):

This can be set when you register your post type. You can add this to your arguments:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'announcement' ),
```

See `register_post_type()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type